# Is any explanation offered for "hyper-sleep"?

Tags: big-hero-6

In Big Hero Six,

> Callahan's daughter was found to be alive in the space between portals in what Baymax describes as "hyper-sleep".

I don't believe the movie offers any further explanation for this, or why Hiro isn't affected.

Are there any other sources that explain this?

Answer (score 5):

### Hypersleep is a feature of the pod

The script mentions hypersleep once. The novelization is only slightly more detailed:

> “My detector is sensing signs of life,” Baymax said.
>
> “What?” Hiro said.
>
> “Coming from there,” Baymax replied, pointing at the portal. “The life
> signs are female. She appears to be in hypersleep.”
>
> <sub>*[Big Hero 6: The Junior Novelization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NI2W2SK)*</sub>

With this in mind, it seems likely that hypersleep was not a feature of the dimension itself, but rather of the pod. That a medical robot recognized hypersleep suggests that it was a recognized medical technique, not the unknown effects of an alien dimension. The purpose of hypersleep was presumably to preserve the pilot in case of long journeys—in other words, as a failsafe against precisely the sort of situation that Abigail ended up in. Thus there would be no reason for Hiro to be affected, since he was never in the pod.